# Update CRM data using Excel sheet and custom identifier

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have to import data from a foreign system into a CRM instance. The foreign system has an ID for either a contact or account (which is also present in CRM, the common identifier).

I'm wondering if it would be possible to extract that data simply through SQL Management Studio, paste this in an Excel file, upload that file through Data Management and have CRM recognize a certain column (the common identifier) as the key, and update all the other fields that would present in that Excel file I plan to upload.

For example, in said foreign system I have:

```
ClientID    ValueNotPresentInCrm
344555      Bleh
```

And currently, in CRM, I have

```
accountid                             xmr_clientid    xmr_ValueNotPresentInCrm
24436EDB-9CFA-E511-80C0-00155D7B5806  344555
```

Obviously, I want to update the `xmr_ValueNotPresentInCrm` column.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: you can use SSIS with KingswaySoft CRM Adapter

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct flavours of Excel upload in CRM.

1. Create new records.
2. Update existing records.

You will need to use option 2, this involves downloading an Excel file (actually XML) which contains the existing records, making changes in Excel, uploading the file again.

Its a little long winded but is the simplest solution. [PowerObjects has a nice tutorial here](http://www.powerobjects.com/2011/09/27/mass-editing-dynamics-crm-2011-records-using-microsoft-excel/).

Answer (score 1):

I would also take a look at the [Configuration Migration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647421.aspx) tool from the SDK. It allows you to specify a uniqueness condition on import (see [step 12](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647422.aspx)), which would be particularly useful to your scenario.

There is also an open source, custom tool called the [Dynamics CRM Configuration Data Mover](http://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2016/01/29/dynamics-crm-configuration-data-mover-v1-5/) which you also may find useful.  It's less relevant to your scenario because it doesn't seem to have an equivalent uniqueness condition feature, but it's still worth noting.